# unable to create a foreign key constraint in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am unable to create a foreign key constraint in mysql for the column "vsa", below is my table structure. i am getting error as "Error creating foreign key on vsa(check data types)". Here I don't see any issues with data type. What am i Missing.

`` CREATE TABLE `child` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `day` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `vsa` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; ``

`` CREATE TABLE `parent` (
  `price_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `device_id` text NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `vsa` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; ``

As an alternative approach I run the alter query to add a constraint. I am getting below error.

````
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
for correct foreign key definition. ```
````

Comment: You have no index on `vsa`, as the first part of the error message says.

Comment: Thanks @Nick after adding the index it worked

Comment: Which column is primary key ?